# Regex in .NET with mixed multiline and singleline requirement

Tags: c#, regex

Could anyone please help me with the following regex-problem:

I have a string which looks like this (for example):

```
10 ExpressionName1 ExpressionParam1.
   10 ExpressionName2 ExpressionParam2.
 10 ExpressionName3 
                   ExpressionParam3.
  10 ExpressionName4 
                        ExpressionParam4_1 ExpressionParam4_2    .
10 ExpressionName5 ExpressionParam5_1 ExpressionParam5_1.
```

Each number 10 represents an expression with a name, one or more parameters and as termination a dot.
Each expression must start in a separate line and can end (dot) in the same or a following line.
Now I would like to regex all 5 expressions giving me name and parameters(parameters can be combined in one string). My problem is that I have to use multiline mode in order to select each start of line, but with multiline mode I cannot find the dot if it is not in the same line.

My regex so far would be:

```
^\s*10 (\S*)(.*)\.
```

So basically my problem is that the "(.*)" doesn´t include linebreaks, beause I have to use multiline. So my result is lacking the expressions 3 and 4.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

PS: This website uses the .NET-regex-engine for testing: http://dotnetregexevaluator.andreasandersen.dk/

Comment: It looks perilously close to the point where you should be implementing a proper parser, rather than trying to do it with standalone regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shove this bad boy at the front

```
(?m)
```

This will match multiline

So your regex would look like this

```
(?m)^\s*10 (\S*)([^.]*)\.
```

Comment: This would deliver the first ExpressionName as the first group and all the rest of the string as the second group. I need matches for every 10, eg 5 matches.

Comment: This is it! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Fyi: You can omit the "(?m)". It´s the same result without it. The [^.] did the trick.

Comment: Happy to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the website you linked this should work for you `^\s*10 \S*\s*\S*.*\.`

Comment: this would deliver 5 matches, but not grouped into name and parameters. maybe I´ll use it and split the matchstring myself. thank you.

Comment: Since I wasn't sure of what you wanted to capture I left those out. I hope you can use this to your advantage

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

```
^\s*10 (\S+)\s+(.*)\.
```

Make sure you this option `RegexOptions.Multiline`